# Getting "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory..." when trying to run amplify init

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, aws-amplify

I'm trying to integrate AWS Amplify to my Flutter project, on Windows, VS code.

I installed Amplify CLI via

```
curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o install.cmd && install.cmd
```

I ran `amplify configure` and created an IAM user.

However, after creating a new Flutter project, running `amplify init` results in the error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data\.aws\config'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
at Object.openSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:739:32)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
at Object.readFileSync (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1025:36)
at Object.readFileSync (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:95:26)
at IniLoader.parseFile (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\shared-ini\ini-loader.js:6:47)
at IniLoader.loadFrom (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\shared-ini\ini-loader.js:56:30)
at getRegion (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\node_loader.js:116:32)
at Config.region (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\node_loader.js:171:18)
at Config.set (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:524:39)
at Config.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:359:12)
at Config.each (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:512:32)
at new Config (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:358:19)
at Object.loadServiceClass (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\service.js:108:16)
at Object.Service [as constructor] (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\service.js:47:29)
at new <anonymous> (C:\snapshot\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\util.js:629:24)
at getConfiguredAmplifyClient (C:\snapshot\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\aws-utils\aws-amplify.js:42:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'open',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\SPB_Data\\.aws\\config'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lucked out in noticing that .aws folder was being generated in C:\Users\Username so I simply copied it to C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\SPB_Data where it'd been missing.

The only problem now is when running additional Amplify configure commands, .aws is being updated only in C:\Users\Username , so I have to remember to copy-paste it to SPB_Data after every new profile is created.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).